# Including external jar files to resource path in Rhino shell

Tags: jar, jna, rhino

I am using javascript on a Rhino Shell. I need to add the com.sun.jna.jar to the classpath. Now when I type - js:> Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary
[JavaClass com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary]
This shows that the jna library is accessible by the Rhino Shell? But when I try to use the library: js:> var c=Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance("c");

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '2': JNA native support (win32-x86/2.dll) not found in resource path (C:\ti\ccsv5\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar)**

The resource path(C:\ti\ccsv5......launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar) is the path it shows when I type - js:> print(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

I donot understand how to add the jar files to the resource path.I tried to do it by the Command prompt: *java -cp "path of jar" .name of class containing main*  ---> How do I understand what is the name of the class containing main since Rhino does the conversion from javascripts to classes?
Thanks in Advance.
Sohini.

Comment: Can you post your code or a snippet of what you are typing to run the shell, and also what you are running?

Comment: js:> Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
[JavaClass com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary]  js:> var c= NativeLibrary.getInstance("c");  ReferenceError: "NativeLibrary" is not defined.  js:> var c= Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance("c");  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '2': JNA native support (win32-x86/2.dll) not found in resource path (C:\ti\ccsv5\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar)  The C code contains a function to add the numbers passed to it.Javascript is required to take the input and give an output.I need to connect these two

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the issue is specifically related to Rhino.  Rather, it is a difference between the Linux and Windows system libraries.

The getting started document for JNA, at 
https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md provides the following example:

```
package com.sun.jna.examples;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

/** Simple example of JNA interface mapping and usage. */
public class HelloWorld {

    // This is the standard, stable way of mapping, which supports extensive
    // customization and mapping of Java to native types.

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"),
                               CLibrary.class);

        void printf(String format, Object... args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");
        for (int i=0;i < args.length;i++) {
            CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**The native library loaded depends on the platform you are running the program on:** For Windows you will need to use the 'msvcrt' (Microsoft Visual C Run Time) library; for others, use the 'c' library.

I ran a test case to confirm:

**Running on Windows fails if I try to load the "c" library.**

```
PS C:\Users\jharig\workspace\JNATest> java -cp ".\jna-3.5.2.jar;.\platform-3.5.2.jar;.\js.jar;.\js-14.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> var c = Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance("c");
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'c': JNA native support (win32-amd64/c
.dll) not found in resource path (.\jna-3.5.2.jar;.\platform-3.5.2.jar;.\js.jar;.\js-14.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:220)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:322)
```

**Running on Windows succeeds if I use the 'msvcrt' library.**

```
PS C:\Users\jharig\workspace\JNATest> java -cp ".\jna-3.5.2.jar;.\platform-3.5.2.jar;.\js.jar;.\js-14.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> var c = Packages.com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance("msvcrt");
js> var f = c.getFunction("printf");
js> f.invoke(["Hello World\n"]);
Hello World
js>
```